# Rails Serialized JSON -> no implicit conversion of Hash into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Having collected some JSON from a file using the Curb gem, I assign a portion of it to an instance variable:

```
self.json_stuff = {"title" => json["title"], "description" => json["description"], "image" => json["image"]}.to_json
```

This then gets stored in the database as JSON:

```
serialize :json_stuff, JSON
...
self.save
```

Later on I check for the presence of said `json_stuff`:

```
return self.json_stuff.present?
```

And get the following error:

```
TypeError - no implicit conversion of Hash into String:
  json (1.8.3) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
  json (1.8.3) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
  json (1.8.3) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

I've stepped through the code and I know that the collection of the JSON from the file is done without issue.

Comment: Could you give use more information please, first of all what does `p self.json_stuff`prints ? Furthermore, I think you try to encode your object two times, the first one with `.to_json` which give you a string, and then when you save id with the `serialize` action, could you try to remove `.to_json` from your first line ?

Comment: when I try to inspect the variable in the rails console I get the same error : `no implicit conversion of Hash into String`... I'll look in to the suggestion of it being encoded twice... Thanks for the pointer...

Comment: ...tried removing `to_json` but still getting the same error... When I get the json from the file, I parse it using `JSON.parse`, is this correct?

Comment: We can't guess, you need to give us some code you wrote

Comment: I didn't mean have I used `JSON.parse` correctly, I mean was I right to use `JSON.parse` at all?

Comment: Were you able to figure out what was wrong? We are facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the *present?* method is for **Strings** to check if they are not empty. If you just want to return boolean based on the existence of *json_stuff* you should check if it is *nil* for example with

```
return self.json_stuff.nil?
```

The type of *self.json_stuff* is *Hash* instead of *String*.